# Symfony how to extend default bundle config?

Tags: symfony

Lets imagine i have a bundle with service config loaded via DependencyInjection/VendorAcmeExtension.php

There are Configuration.php class that loads some parameter default value (array of values).

The question: how to extend default values? In theory i have to set param value via config.yml, but this will override default value. But i need to add my value to default value array instead of override this default array

**Update**

Sorry for my engish (

For example vendor bundle have Configuration.php that loads default values:

```
    $rootNode
        ->children()
                ...
                ->defaultValue(
                    array(
                        'entity'=>array(
                            'label' => 'oro.user.privileges.entity.label',
                            'view_type' => 'grid',
                            'types' => array('entity'),
                            'field_type' => 'oro_acl_access_level_selector',
                            'fix_values' => false,
                            'default_value' => 5,
                            'show_default' => true,
                        ),
                        'action'=>array(
                            'label' => 'oro.user.privileges.action.label',
                            'view_type' => 'list',
                            'types' => array('action'),
                            'field_type' => 'oro_acl_access_level_selector',
                            'fix_values' => false,
                            'default_value' => 1,
                            'show_default' => false,
                        )
                    )
                )
                ...
```

This default value contains an array
I need to add new element to this array. If i do this in config.yml - i will overwrite default values. But all i want is to push new element

Comment: huh? what? need to add my value to default value array? please explain a bit more

Comment: sorry, i updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to override parts of a bundle, you could you [bundle inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html), but this is pretty rare IMO.

To override the default configuration, you could just define a [prepended configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html) method; this works just like if you put a config block at the top of your `config.yml` file (sort of).

Comment: Thats it! Thank you, i'll try today. This manual looks like what im looking for